# Using Blogger to power a site's internal blog

Tags: blog, blogger, rss

I would like to add a blog to my site.  I am considering using a Blogger blog which my site would access (probably using the RSS feed) parse, and display using a set of my own HTML templates. I haven't spent the time to figure out how to do this yet.

- It this a good idea to chase after or am I headed down dead end path?
- Would I need to worry about SEO penalties for duplicate content?

I am avoiding installing a formal blog platform on my site (Drupal, WordPress, etc.).

Comment: I cannot answer this question directly, but I thought of using an old GreyMatter blog install to munge the GM files into a blog style portion to one of my sites. I thought this could be a fast and dirty GUI that can be automated easily. I am interested in what you learn. You seem to be doing some rather interesting stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that some people do is

- re-design the blog so that it looks very much like their main site
  (`www.yourdomain.com`)
- set up `www.blog.yourdomain.com`, and redirect their blog to that
  (including having menu bar links back to `www.yourdomain.com`)
- set up a link in their main site to the blog, pointing to
  `www.blog.yourdomain.com`.

That way, visitors switch between the two sites without actually realising they're changing sites.

Of course this only works if your website design is amenable to being replicated in Blogger. And if you have design changes you have to do them in two places.

Answer (score 2):

This can work - but not if you have a private blog on Blogger, because they do not have RSS feeds.

Comment: Good point, The only reason that I would make it private is to have all of the SEO credit for the blog go to my domain.  Still, its all Google anyway.